# Storyboard access UIControl property through global value

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uicontrol

I have an iPhone app with a number of view controllers. Their respective UI is setup in the main storyboard file. For consistency, I have defined some global values for textfield heights, font sizes, button heights etc. that will be used by many controls. The current way of setting up these controls is by initialising them in the storyboard and then in the respective view controller, within viewDidAppear, the global values for heights, fonts and the like are accessed and assigned as the remaining properties of these controls.

But this process is fragmented and prone to error. Is there a better way of doing this? Is it possible to have access to global values, defined in swift files, within the storyboard? For instance, could the font of a textfield pointed to by the Attributes Inspector be actually referencing a global value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set what you want , if you have a pre-defined height/Font , then set it directly in attributes inspector , if you want to configure for different devices you can try with size classes

**Or**

Create sub classes of the elements you want ( `UITextField` / `UIIButton` ) , and assign them to class name in IB

Comment: You could create a example of a subclass of, e.g. `UIButton` using the constant data for people who do not have much experience.

Comment: I ended up adding custom classes for the desired elements, it wasn't that bad.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to pre-process the story board file. Run a script that searches the related XML elements in the storyboard file and replaces them with the correct values. You may want to add it as a run-script phase so it would run before each compilation (I have not tried that one but it seems possible, though you would not see the fixed values in storyboard while developing), or just run it manually from the command line.

Comment: This is the solution I would go for, but the fact that I could not see the various values in IB was a deal breaker.